# Displaying a profile photo rather then a link to that photo

Tags: php, sql

I am working through a chapter of a book with regards to binary data.  What I would like to do is to automatically display a picture of a person as my database deals with profiles.

So far my solution works and the photo is the last piece of the puzzle.

The book gets you to the stage where a filename link is outputted to the screen, and clicking on this link displays the picture.

What I would like to do instead of this is have the picture displayed automatically like for instance on Facebook.  There you would not see a link to your profile picture but the actual picture itself.

Code looks like this:

INDEX.PHP (Controller)

```
<?php
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/magicquotes.inc.php';

if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'upload')
{
  // Bail out if the file isn't really an upload
  if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']))
  {
    $error = 'There was no file uploaded!';
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/error.html.php';
    exit();
  }
  $uploadfile = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
  $uploadname = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
  $uploadtype = $_FILES['upload']['type'];
  $uploaddesc = $_POST['desc'];
  $uploaddata = file_get_contents($uploadfile);

  include 'db.inc.php';

  try
  {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO filestore SET
        filename = :filename,
        mimetype = :mimetype,
        description = :description,
        filedata = :filedata';
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':filename', $uploadname);
    $s->bindValue(':mimetype', $uploadtype);
    $s->bindValue(':description', $uploaddesc);
    $s->bindValue(':filedata', $uploaddata);
    $s->execute();
  }
  catch (PDOException $e)
  {
    $error = 'Database error storing file!';
     include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/error.html.php';
    exit();
  }

  header('Location: .');
  exit();
}

if (isset($_GET['action']) and
    ($_GET['action'] == 'view' or $_GET['action'] == 'download') and
    isset($_GET['id']))
{
  include 'db.inc.php';

  try
  {
    $sql = 'SELECT filename, mimetype, filedata
        FROM filestore
        WHERE id = :id';
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':id', $_GET['id']);
    $s->execute();
  }
  catch (PDOException $e)
  {
    $error = 'Database error fetching requested file.';
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/error.html.php';
    exit();
  }

  $file = $s->fetch();
  if (!$file)
  {
    $error = 'File with specified ID not found in the database!';
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/error.html.php';
    exit();
  }

  $filename = $file['filename'];
  $mimetype = $file['mimetype'];
  $filedata = $file['filedata'];
  $disposition = 'inline';

  if ($_GET['action'] == 'download')
  {
     $mimetype = 'application/octet-stream';
     $disposition = 'attachment';
  }

  // Content-type must come before Content-disposition
  header('Content-length: ' . strlen($filedata));
  header("Content-type: $mimetype");
  header("Content-disposition: $disposition; filename=$filename");

  echo $filedata;
  exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'delete' and
    isset($_POST['id']))
{
  include 'db.inc.php';

  try
  {
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM filestore
        WHERE id = :id';
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
    $s->execute();
  }
  catch (PDOException $e)
  {
    $error = 'Database error deleting requested file.';
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/error.html.php';
    exit();
  }

  header('Location: .');
  exit();
}

include 'db.inc.php';

try
{
  $result = $pdo->query(
      'SELECT id, filename, mimetype, description
      FROM filestore');
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  $error = 'Database error fetching stored files.';
  include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/error.html.php';
  exit();
}

$files = array();
foreach ($result as $row)
{
  $files[] = array(
      'id' => $row['id'],
       'filename' => $row['filename'],
       'mimetype' => $row['mimetype'],
       'description' => $row['description']);
}

include 'files.html.php';
```

PHOTO.HTML (View)

```
<?php include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/helpers.inc.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PHP/MySQL File Repository</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>PHP/MySQL File Repository</h1>

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div>
        <label for="upload">Upload File:
        <input type="file" id="upload" name="upload"></label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="desc">File Description:
        <input type="text" id="desc" name="desc" maxlength="255"></label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="upload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
      </div>
    </form>

    <?php if (count($files) > 0): ?>

    <p>The following files are stored in the database:</p>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Filename</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php foreach($files as $f): ?>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="?action=view&amp;id=<?php htmlout($f['id']); ?>"
                ><?php htmlout($f['filename']); ?></a>
          </td>
          <td><?php htmlout($f['mimetype']); ?></td>
          <td><?php htmlout($f['description']); ?></td>
          <td><?php htmlout($f['filedata']); ?></td>

          <td>
            <form action="" method="get">
              <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="download"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php htmlout($f['id']); ?>"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Download"/>
              </div>
            </form>
          </td>
          <td>
            <form action="" method="post">
              <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php htmlout($f['id']); ?>"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
              </div>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php endif; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

All help is appreciated.

EXTRACT OF CURRENT PHOTO.HTML

```
<?php foreach($files as $f): ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="?action=view&amp;id=<?php htmlout($f['id']); ?>"
            ><?php htmlout($f['filename']); ?></a>

            <!-- attempt to output image not path -->
            <img src="<?php echo htmlout($f['filename']); ?>" />
      </td>
```

HELPER FUNCTION

```
<?php

function html($text)
{
    return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

function htmlout($text)
{
    echo html($text);
}

?>
```

Comment: Was an `<img>` tag insufficient?

Comment: Apologies for this question showing a lack of thought but I was stumped and do not know where to begin.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in an `<img>` tag. This will output it as an image.

i.e. `<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>">`

Comment: @MarcB - It was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: @Johnny This works. If this doesn't work for you, then there's an issue with the script that produces the image (provided that `$image` is set to the URL of the script that writes the image).

Comment: As @Matt said, it will work. Can you show your attempt? Otherwise, something else is wrong in your code.

Comment: Okay so this `code`<a href="?action=view&amp;id=<?php htmlout($f['id']); ?>"><?php htmlout($f['filename']); ?></a>`code` represents the link that when clicked on shows the image.  So I need to wrap this in an img tag right?  So minus link part I have `code`<img src="<?php htmlout($f['filename']); ?>" />`code`.  This shows no image.

Comment: If I compare this URL with the URL I get when I click on the current link being generate, they are not the same, which obviously I need them to be.  My attempt produces the link http://localhost:81/chapter12/filestore/testpic.jpg whereas I need it to be http://localhost:81/chapter12/filestore/?action=view&id=2.  Thoughts?  Am defo confused on this one but thanks for your help.

Comment: You forgot to `echo` it `<img src="<?php echo htmlout($f['filename']); ?>" />`

Comment: Still does not work.  The URL is stil http://localhost:81/chapter12/filestore/testpic.jpg when using the above even though I am now using the echo.

Comment: Please edit your original question and place the code in there. It's hard to read it in the comments.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  Done this.  Added new extract.

Comment: Just a helper function to output text, have added another extract.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you are going to be better served by keeping the image files somewhere on a directory structure that is publicly available via HTTP and just storing the link to that image location in the database.

So for example when the user uploads the image, you place it within your web directory in some user images directory, and then just store the path or URL for the image in the database in a varchar field.

This gives you the benefit of keeping your database size down, making your queries for picture information from the database go much faster, improving browser caching of the images, and allowing you to keep your static files in one place (perhaps on a CDN again for better performance in end user's browsers).

Comment: Any examples of how this can be acheived?

Comment: There are any number of examples on StackOverflow or the internet at large that show how to write the content of $_FILES to a local directory on the machine.  You would then just take that string value that represents where the file was written and put it into the database. Say `$filepath = '/images/profiles/' . $uploadname` which might correspond to a physical location on disk of `/var/www/images/profiles/UPLOADNAME`.  You save `$filepath` to teh database and when printing out your HTML source, you would just do `<img src="<?php echo $filepath_from_db; ?>"/>`